# writing to a .json file what is being used as a log in system, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im setting up a dice roll game for a computing gcse. I am having some troubles with adding new user to my *.json* file. I am new to coding and not the greatest at it so any help would appreciated! I want it to add a new usernames and passwords in the format `{"username":"password"}`

I have looked around on this forum and have tried changing how it is opening the file such as `a` and `w`. I get confused by all of the answers and cannot relate it to mine.

```
    path_to_json = "./logins.json"
    logins = json.load(open("logins.json", "a"))
    username = (input('New Username: '))
    password = (input('New Password: '))

    logins = ['login'].append({username:password})

    with open('logins.json', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(logins)
```

I am hoping it will add a user however I am getting the errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       new_user()   File "N:\NEA Computing\NEA code.py", line 32, in new_user
>       logins = json.load(open("logins.json", "a"))   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json__init__.py", line 296, in load
>       return loads(fp.read(), io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

I have got a *.json* file in my directories on my computer.

Comment: share this file `NEA code.py`

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Hi there, I am do not know how to share the file. I am new to this website

Comment: I have searched up some error codes and emailed my brother as he is a lot wiser than me in this field. I have changed how it opens the file such as r for read or a for append or w for write

Comment: can you share `json` file format?

Answer (score 2):

Change the "a" to "r" in order for your file to be readable.

```py
 logins = json.load(open("logins.json", "r"))
```

Comment: OP was trying to open file with `append` mode to read which was causing the problem. +1

Comment: Hi there, this has helped to remove some errors however i have a error saying i am ```NameError: name 'fp' is not defined``` this is for the line ```json.dump(logins)```

Comment: Write `json.dump(logins, outfile)` as `json.dump` accept a second argument named  `fp`, which you have not provided

Answer (score 0):

@kuco23 solved first issue but there were several other of them. First being, you don't have to assign while using `append()` on Python lists. While second being, `dump()` expects a file pointer as another parameter.

Also, I'm not sure why you were using append more for writing since you are already appending in list. I changed that to write mode.

```
import json

path_to_json = "./logins.json"
with open("logins.json", "r") as content:
    logins = json.load(content)

username = input('New Username: ')
password = input('New Password: ')

logins.append({username: password})

with open("logins.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(logins, outfile)
```

Or something closer to what OP did

```
import json

path_to_json = "./logins.json"
logins = json.load(open("logins.json", "r"))

username = input("New Username: ")
password = input("New Password: ")

logins.append({username: password})

json.dump(logins, open("logins.json", "w"))
```

Comment: Hi there, am i meant to change the ```content``` to another variable or word? new to this so am little confused. From the looks from this yo hit the nail on the head with your answer

Comment: @Cflux `content` variable name doesn't really matter here. `with` is just another safe approach of opening file in Python which I have habit of using. Opening file like you mentioned is okay as well, just don't forget to use right mode, i.e., `read`, `write` or `append`